# How does Google's "No CAPTCHA reCAPTCHA" work?

Tags: jquery, captcha, recaptcha, bots

I am trying to build a ReCaptcha-like jquery plugin. So far, I have completed the visual aspect.

Any idea how it works under the hood so that I can replicate the same in my plugin?

Answer (score 0):

Where to begin...

- Google has a LOT of knowledge about many browsers and IP addresses thanks to Google Search, Google Analytics, Google Adsense that they can use to influence their decision as to whether or not you are a bot or legit browser with some history
- They use Javascript to track your mouse movements and keyboard input on the page and use complex algorithms server side to analyze them to help decide if you are a bot
- They use Javascript to look at various properties of the browser (e.g. screen & viewport resolution, plugins, fonts and use complex server side algorithms to help decide if you are a bot
- They probably use their vast troves of data to see if the IP has been challenged many times by reCaptcha in recent time or historically (signs of a bot, a normal user might encounter a few challenges a day, not many hundreds or thousands)
- I think sometimes they try to use client side Javascript to inject plugins or other code into the page and then analyze it server side to test if the Javascript was run (could signal a bot if the code never runs)
- Probably a bunch of other stuff we don't know about because if we did the "bad guys" would use it to defeat reCaptcha

Then if they determine you are a bot or can't decide, they show a normal alphanumeric or image captcha.

Keep in mind, if your captcha is 100% client side jQuery/Javascript, it can and will be easily bypassed.  You need some server side processing (PHP, .NET, JSP etc).